# Substring removes 2 characters instead of 1

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, substring

My assignment requires me to have this clear last button which removes the last character in a string. as seen from the code, it  SHOULD exclude that last number.

Problem is that when I press it the first time after inputting numbers, it removes 2 and subsequent uses take out 1. any idea how to fix this?

code:

```
case "Clear Last":
    String remove;
    remove = text.substring(text.length()-1);
    switch (remove) {
        case "+":
            add = false;
            text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);                    
            display.setText(text);
            break;
        case "-":
            subtract = false;
            text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);                    
            display.setText(text);
            break;
        case "*":
            multiply = false;
            text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);                    
            display.setText(text);
            break;
        case "/":
            divide = false;
            text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);                    
            display.setText(text);
            break;
        default:
                text = text.substring(0, text.length()-1);
                display.setText(text);
            break;
    }
    break;
```

Example output:

77777 -> Clear Last -> 777 -> Clear Last -> 77 -> 778888 -> Clear Last -> 7788 -> Clear Last -> 778

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: it's a java GUI Calculator so it might be a little big. I'll add it in the OP then @shmosel

Comment: If it's big, cut it down to just the code necessary to reproduce the problem. You might even discover the problem yourself in the process.

Comment: @shmosel done. still pretty big tho. removed it from the package so it should run a bit easier

Comment: Why do you have so much duplicated code?

Comment: Be sure to remember that substring and the length of the string are going to be different; the length starts counting from 1, but the substring starts counting from 0.

Comment: It's a calculator that uses a GUI. I've combined declaration of each button number and its respectively actionlistener. Then, they are placed in a JPanel where they are given an interactive button. The action listener determines which button is pressed and does it's respective action.

Comment: @oriont I tried that and while it did work, it only worked once. Pressing it a second time without pressure a number button instead doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here (and all such snippets):-

```
text = display.getText();
display.setText(text + "7");
```

You are updating the `text` **before** you update the `display`. You should interchange them and it should work:-

```
display.setText(text + "7");
text = display.getText();
```

Even better, just update the value of `text` and set `display` outside `switch`, something like this:-

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
        case "1":
        case "2":
        case "3":
        case "4":
        case "5":
        case "6":
        case "7":
        case "8":
        case "9":
        case "0":
        case ".":
            text += e.getActionCommand();
            break;
        case "=":
            break;
        case "Clear Last":
            text = text.substring(0, (text.length() - 1));
            break;
        case "Clear All":
            text = "";
            break;
        default:
            text = "";
            break;
    }
    display.setText(text);
}
```

Or improve it even further by getting rid of the switch-case - check if `e.getActionCommand()` is a digit, then do `text += e.getActionCommand();`, else if....

Comment: Wow. Didn't know that was possible reducing the code down hard like that. It's beautiful. I'll try this out right now.

Comment: Hot damn. This worked! Thank you so much! That text += e.getActionCommand(); worked perfectly! Now I'll have to set another switch statement so it does nothing if text is null or it's length is 0 or less.

Comment: your `default` case should handle it.. if you want to do it manually, you can write `if (e.getActionCommand() != null && !e.getActionCommand().isEmpty())` just before the `switch`.. Java is beautiful, isn't it?